# Painlessly updating from Ubuntu 10.04 to 11.04 or 11.x

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, 10.04, updates, xorg

Is there a way to update from 10.04 to 11.04? I see an option to update to 12.04 LTS but I would rather keep it 11.04 because the new UI is terrible :)

It's because of nvidia drivers and failing to set them up on a 2.6.32-lts when the drivers need 2.6.34-ARCH or something such....

If there is no way to update to 11.04, is there a way to use 12.04 so that it looks like the good ol' 11.04? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10.04 and 12.04 are both LTS releases, which is why you can upgrade directly to 12.04. 11.04 and 11.10 are both end of life now, meaning they're unavailable for standard download (you *could* probably hack around this but it's not a good idea).

I would personally recommend upgrading to 12.04 and fixing what you don't like.

If you're unhappy with Unity, Compiz or whatever in the latest release, you can try other things. KDE (`kubuntu-desktop` package) provided me with a happy place to call Home but other people swear by XFCE and LDXE, even Enlightenment. Everybody likes something different...

The point I'm trying to make is you're not stuck with what you're given. And testing another desktop is relatively simple and non-destructive.

Comment: I'm quite happy with how it looked like in 11.04 that's the thing. But at least now I know I can't update to 11.04 and simply have to go with 12.04.

And yea, I decided to ask for help after some 45 mins of `hacking around`) :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Oli for pointing out the updating issue, but as for Gnome I think I'll give this (http://pleasanthacking.com/2012/01/02/making-ubuntu-11-10-and-12-04-behave-like-10-04/) a shot.

```
#gnome
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-session-fallback gnome-tweak-tool

#ported indicator
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet indicator-applet-complete indicator-applet-session indicator-applet-appmenu

#compiz
sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra

#radiance 10.04
wget http://light-themes-lucid.googlecode.com/files/Radiance-10.04a-gtk3-gtk2.tgz
sudo tar -xzf Radiance-10.04a-gtk3-gtk2.tgz -C /usr/share/themes
```

Hopefully, it'll do the trick.

Comment: Speaking as somebody who went through this problem at the time, fallback is close but not quite the same. It's also not maintained to the same degree as Gnome2-proper was. I advise shopping around for a permanent replacement.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? I have a rather unusual setup here, and this host OS I'm currently trying to fix will - hopefully - just be a shell around a well-working ubuntu VM... for which I'll just miss vmware-tools or some such. Seeing how I have crappy graphics in my host OS and the virtual one I figured fixing the host might help.

Comment: You should try alternate desktops, personally I have gone to KDE (kubuntu), you might prefer xubuntu or lubuntu, only you can decide. Boot the various live iso in vmware and decide for yourself what you like.

Comment: For what it's worth, what I wrote resulted in garbage. However, this new 12.04 looks purpose-built as a 11.04 VM wrapper :D